# Php functio Order Images

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have this function that what it does is turn over all the content of images in a folder and show it to me on the screen.

What I want is that the function shows me the images ordered by the numerical name that I have given them to the images.

```php
<?php
   $folder_path = 'images/2019-01-12_Regata_Castelldefels/'; //image's folder path

   $num_files = glob($folder_path . "*.{JPG,jpg,gif,png,bmp}", GLOB_BRACE);

   $folder = opendir($folder_path);

   if($num_files > 0){
     while(false !== ($file = readdir($folder))){
          $file_path = $folder_path.$file;
          $extension = strtolower(pathinfo($file ,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
          if($extension=='jpg' || $extension =='png' || $extension == 'gif' || $extension == 'bmp'){
?>
  <div class="column">
      <a class="example-image-link" href="<?php echo $file_path; ?>" data-lightbox="example-set" ><img src="<?php echo $file_path; ?>"style="width:100%" /></a>
   </div>
<?php
    }
  }
}
 else {
   echo "No existeix la carpeta!";
  }
 closedir($folder);
?>
```

Comment: can you clarify the style of names assigned to the images? Are they like `1.jpg`, `2.jpg` etc?

Comment: Yes is a 1.jpg, 2.jpg, etc

Answer (score 0):

A lightly different approach would be to use the `glob` in a different manner - to actually find the files that will be sorted rather than to provide a count.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Sorted Images</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php


            $dir = 'images/2019-01-12_Regata_Castelldefels/';

            /* Capture all files that match the extensions listed here */
            $col = preg_grep( '@(\.jpg|\.png|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.bmp)@i', glob( $dir . '*.*' ) );

            /* OK, found some files... */
            if( count( $col ) > 0 ){

                /* create and populate array of filenames which will be sorted */
                $tmp=[];
                foreach( $col as $img )$tmp[]=pathinfo( $img, PATHINFO_BASENAME );

                /* numerically sort the array of file names */
                sort( $tmp, SORT_NUMERIC );

                /* iterate through this array of filenames and render to screen */
                foreach( $tmp as $img ){
                    printf(
                        '<div class="column">
                            <a href="%1$s/%2$s" class="example-image-link" data-lightbox="example-set">
                                <img src="%1$s/%2$s" style="width:100%%%" alt="%2$s" title="%2$s" />
                            </a>
                        </div>',
                        rtrim( $dir , '/' ),
                        $img
                    );
                }
            } else {
                echo "No files...";
            }
        ?>  
    </body>
</html>
```

To display the images within a single div, of class `column` simply move that portion of code outside the loop, like so:

```
echo '
<div class="column">';

/* iterate through this array of filenames and render to screen */
foreach( $tmp as $i => $img ){
    printf(
        '
        <!-- %3$d -->
        <a href="%1$s/%2$s" class="example-image-link" data-lightbox="example-set">
            <img src="%1$s/%2$s" style="width:100%%%" alt="%2$s" title="%2$s" />
        </a>',
        rtrim( $dir , '/' ),
        $img,
        $i
    );
}

echo '
</div>';
```

Comment: The only thing that I have to show the images inside the div class columns works perfectly because the div makes a gallery of images

Comment: sorry - you lost me there. Does the above not work?

Comment: But I need the images to be displayed inside the div class column i with the classes and styles that there within the div column

Comment: do you mean a single div ( `class='column'` ) is to hold all the hyperlink / images?

Comment: Yes is to hold all the hyperlink / images